# Decode rs-422 without line receiver

Tags: signal, differential, rs422

I have a encoder on a dc motor that outputs it's signals as RS-422. `A`, `~A`, `B` and `~B` so it just sends to raw ticks of the encoder and not serial data.

I didn't have a line receiver available so a colleague thought to test we can just connect the `A` and `B` lines to a microcontroller and use those. I thought this should work as well but we are seeing weird transition in the encoder pattern that shouldn't physically be possible.

So searching online I found discussion such as this:
[Can I an RS422 interface to Arduino's serial pins?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/160551/can-i-an-rs422-interface-to-arduinos-serial-pins)

which say without really explaining that you really do need to decode the signals for it to work. So my question is basically. Could the reason be that I see weird encoder transition be due to us not using a proper line-receiver? And also why isn't it the case that just connecting the positive signals is enough.

Be aware the cable from the encoder to the MCU is just a couple of inches.

Comment: What about the return signal? I think the ~A and ~B are also required.

Comment: What is this weird transition that should not be possible?

Comment: RS-422 signal levels should be 0 V or (almost) +5 V. If you are using a 3.3 V microcontroller it may well not like seeing 5 V on an input. You'll need a common ground reference between the encoder and the microcontroller. Even with a proper differential receiver you'll still need a common ground reference as the common mode voltage range is only 7 V outside the signal level (hence -7 V to +12 V) unless you have isolated connections.

Answer (score 3):

So, your A and ~A form a differential pair – and as it's only required that the relative voltage of these reflect the data signal, a totally legal differential signal would fix A at 6 V, and make ~A alternate between 4.5 V and 7.5V (if you're going for a 1.5V differential voltage). AC coupling might also be part of the line driver - if the protocol ensures sufficient rate of state changes, e.g. through line coding, in which case the ground-referenced voltages on A or ~A might also be negative for short durations, even without anyone actually having any negative supply voltage.

So, long story short: you have differential line. Build a differential receiver!

That needn't be problematic or expensive. As said, if the protocol ensures sufficient numbers of bit transitions, just using something stupidly simple as

```
       +VCC
         |
       |10kΩ|
         |
A---||---+-------\   |\
         |        ---|+\
       |100Ω|        |  >--MCU
         |        ---|-/
~A--||---+-------/   |/
         |
       |10kΩ|
         |
        GND
```

Would probably suffice to receive differentially. Whether or not you use an external comparator or a comparator built-in to your MCU depends on whether your MCU has these. (many do, but then again, if you had one, you probably would have no problem.)

But honestly: get a darn RS-422 receiver. [These](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/maxlinear-inc/XR33180ESBTR/1016-2140-2-ND/6193847) are 3mm × 3mm including leads and cost something between 23 and 56 ct. This seems to be a no-brainer, unless you need to cost-optimize for > 10⁴ devices, in which case the answer might be: get a MCU with a differential RS-422 receiver built in.

Answer (score 1):

You could feed both lines to a comparator if you don't have a line receiver.

For what it is worth, when I came onto a project I found an RS-422 encoder wired the same way and it worked for the most part. It wasn't until we started needing to hunt down EMI and jitter issues that I realized it was wired that way.

Ultimately, I did end up installing a line driver since we were having EMI issues, were extending the run distance, and multi-dropping the encoder signal. It never did fix our noise issue. I ended up having to program blanking and filtering into the FPGA so it would ignore the noise spikes.

Answer (score 0):

To get it right .. There must be A+/A-,B+/B-,GND ..

Yes .. you can 'see' the proper signal just from A+,B+,GND .. but to interface it to MCU or else you need a line receiver, something like SN75176 or alike ..

Fast optocoupler or comparator can do the trick too..